# Set number of audible rings

Tags: iphone, ios, ringtones

I've found articles on setting the number of rings before my phone goes to voicemail, but I want something different:

I want something in between "silent" and "ringing out loud the default number times (7 or so)".

I want the phone to ring out loud once or twice, and then continue to "ring" silently -- ie, I would still have time to get to my phone before it went to voicemail.

The problem is that 7 rings is almost never needed, since I hear the phone on the first or second ring -- the remaining rings are just an insistent audio annoyance.

Comment: How about making a ringtone 40s long but silent after 5s? On phone so will make into an answer later.

Comment: In case you don’t know this already: if you press the sleep button while the phone is ringing it silences it like you want. However, it seems Nimesh is right that there is no setting to automate this.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Brilliant idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a ringtone 40 seconds long, but containing only silence after the first 5 seconds or so.

[Digital Trends have a full tutorial](https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-make-ringtones-for-iphone/), though it's using an existing tune from iTunes. They also say maximum ringtone length is 30s. I always thought it was 40, so you might need to experiment.

You could quite easily do this in something like [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org). Copy in 5s of audio but save a file 30s long. I'm not sure whether it can save AAC, but if not, save as WAV then use something like [XLD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xld/) to convert to AAC [m4a]. Manually change the extension to m4r & you have a ringtone.

Comment: Ringtone duration is limited to 30 seconds. Isn't the tone played over again and again in loop till the call is answered? This technique may not work in that case.

Comment: Mine goes to voicemail before it reaches the end of a long ringtone. The longest one I have is 39 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

There in no setting/configuration available in iOS which can be used to achieve the desired customization.

I think the prevailing solution is to silence the audible ringer and wear an Apple watch so you can discretly check on a call and answer directly or choose to handle the call on the phone. For the near future, the phone will likely ring when it's ringing and not when it's not.